# List<Task> class/controller to prevent memory exhaustion

Tags: c#

In my Outlook spam add-on when I receive a new email I create a new task to process the email.

That way I don't block Outlook itself.

To prevent the List collection from growing exponentially, (traditionally Outlook is not closed for a long, long time), I have created a simple `TasksController` class that will help me keeping the list to a manageable size.

Then I can simply call:

```
TasksController.Add( ProcessNewEmail() ) 
... 
private async Task<bool> ProcessNewEmail()
{
   /// ... do stuff
}
```

This is the class itself

```
internal class TasksController : IDisposable
{
  private static TasksController _controller;

  private static TasksController Controller => _controller ?? (_controller = new TasksController());

  private readonly object _lock = new object();
  private readonly List<Task> _tasks;

  private TasksController()
  {
    _tasks = new List<Task>();
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    WaitAll();
  }

  private void _Add( Task run )
  {
    //  remove all the completed tasks
    RemoveAllCompleted();

    // and add the new task
    lock (_lock)
    {
      _tasks.Add(run);
    }
  }

  private void _WaitAll()
  {
    lock (_lock)
    {
      Task.WaitAll(_tasks.ToArray());
    }
    RemoveAllCompleted();
  }

  private void RemoveAllCompleted()
  {
    lock(_lock)
    {
      _tasks.RemoveAll(t => t.IsCompleted);
    }
  }

  public static void WaitAll()
  {
    Controller._WaitAll();
  }

  public static void Add(Task run)
  {
    Controller._Add( run );
  }
}
```

Is deriving from `IDisposable` necessary?
Is the class itself thread safe?

Comment: Not exactly same requirements but similar.  you should check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/177853/52662  It's a self removing way instead of holding onto task that are already completed.

Answer (score 2):

**Is the class itself thread safe**

Looks fairly safe except `TasksController Controller` part.

Firstly, I would suggest to use .NET classes for storing concurent data instead of `List<T>` depending on your needs you can use `ConcurrentBag<T>`, `ConcurrentQueue<T>`. 
Secondly, create lock for `TasksController Controller` and use it inside getter. Something like this:

```
private static TasksController Controller {
    get{
        lock(_controllerLock){ 
           if(_controller == null){ (_controller = new TasksController();} 
           return _controller
        }
    }}
```

**Is deriving from IDisposable necessary**

I would say: *no*. All tasks should be disposed automatically when they finish.

However, there is only one *but*, you might to cancell your tasks when object is being disposed. That means if they do some heavy calculations which you do not need anymore after main object disposes. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196889/cancelling-tasks-in-the-dispose-method) for information how to do that.

For more information about disposing tasks see [MSDN blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/25/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks)

Comment: Ok, I will make `_controller` volatile and do a double lock check, might be an overkill to double check, but it would prevent unneeded locks.

I agree with IDisposable, but I am worried that the list will just be cleared and we will not wait for Tasks to complete, and as you said, I might want to cancel the tasks.

Comment: `ConcurrentBag<>` are nice, except when removing items. Not sure what is more efficient a lock or cloning to remove completed tasks.

Comment: This is not a double check if you want to make `TasksController` fully thread safe.  I don't know how your ` ProcessNewEmail()` method is efficent but I if it takes some time then you can safely ignore overhead of `ConcurentBag<T>`.  Another thinkg that came into my mind today, you can always use [thread pool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx) which can wrap up  your tasks nicely.